# when to escape user input

Tags: web-application, attack-prevention

I wonder when is the best way to handle escaping user input.

Two options come to my mind

1) User sends data to server we escape it and then store it into database
2) we store data as it is and escape it when we send data to user.

To me it seems a lot easier escaping and then saving data to database but lets suppose someone finds flow in our website and manages to avoid escaping we have a problem of finding all data that we stored to database un-escaped

on the other hand if we just store data as it is but escape it once we send it to user even if someone finds flow in our website all we have to do is fix bug as our system already assumes that data saved in database in not escaped.

Although second approach seems easier it seems a lot more prone to error. Suppose we generate HTML on server and send it to user and then decide to switch to just sending content to user via ajax, it is easy to forget that we need to escape all the data before sending it to user or implementing new API, or something third.

So I wonder what is preferable way of handling this?

Answer (score 13):

User input is a string. *Escaping* is done when you want to insert some characters into some HTML / SQL / Whatever code which insists on *interpreting* some characters into special functionalities. For instance, you have a '<' and you want it to be shown back to the user as a '<', but if you brutally paste the string inside the HTML then the Web browser on the client side will look at the '<' and think that it begins some HTML tag, instead of representing a simple '<'.

**In general**, you want to keep strings as strings, and delegate any encoding or escaping to specialized functions which do that well. For instance, for SQL, you use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). With HTML from a PHP context, you would use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

The point to notice here is that the kind of conversion, encoding or escaping that you need to perform depends on what you are trying to do with the string. If you need the string to put it in some HTML then you'll use HTML entities (the `&lt;` for '<' and so on). If you store in the database the *already escaped* string, then you are betting that you will use the string *only* by including it in some HTML.

So you should strive to apply encoding/escaping only upon usage. It is more flexible and makes semantics simpler. Within your database, store the string as a string.

Comment: Additionally, for exceptionally high-performance environments where you are certain the data will never be used elsewhere, you might store it in an escaped form. Otherwise, store it in its raw form as suggested in this answer.

Comment: +1 deal with escaping at the point you're injecting - anything else leaves you with broken separation-of-concerns which is very hard to maintain consistently. Prefer methods that automatically get it right because the manual way can easily be forgotten: parameterised queries are preferable to calling `mysql_real_escape_string` every time and similarly using a templating language that defaults to HTML-escaping everything is in principle preferable to calling `htmlspecialchars()` every time.

Comment: I've been looking for the basic definition of 'escaping' and haven't found one. So simply put escaping is a technique to ensure a string is interpreted as just a string and not run as code?

Comment: "Escaping" is related to _interpretation of data_. In most text-based languages (e.g. SQL, HTML...), there are literal values which are strings of characters; most of the characters just stand for themselves, but a few trigger special processing. For instance, in a string delimited by double-quotes, the `"` character triggers the end of string. If you want to include a double-quote in the string contents, then that special behaviour must be deactivated. "Escaping" is replacing a character _x_ into a sequence (starting with another special char) that results in a non-special _x_ (e.g. `\"`).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**  Luc has pointed out in the concept that I'm unduly slanted towards high-performance solutions.   If, in your situation, performance isn't a concern, then it's perfectly acceptable (and preferable, in fact) to store the original data alone and transform it on output.  This gives you flexibility to use the data however you need you without maintaining versions.

Original answer below ------------------------------------------------------

To some degree, it depends.   First, the answer is rarely to store the raw data and escape it when you read it back out.

The two common solutions are:

1) Escape the data before storing it.

2) Store two copies of the data, one escaped, and one raw.

In virtually any system the ratio of reads to writes is going to be heavily, heavily canted towards reads.  It may be 10:1, but it could be 10,000:1.   This is why you want to store the data in an escaped format and only parse it when you're writing it, not every single time you want to read it.

The benefit of storing both formats is that the original author can modify the content as intended, you can re-process it if you like, you can review the original data...It gives you some additional flexibility at the expense of a little additional complexity.

This is obviously a bit simplistic, as for instance I'm not considering the effects of caching on the read/write ratio, but it hopefully it conveys the general concept.

Comment: You don't ever save two copies of the same data. I can't imagine that being a common solution.

Comment: @Luc That is factually incorrect.  Many, many systems save both original, and formatted-in-some-manner copies  of the same data, whether it's escaped, or lower-cased, or otherwise genericized.

Comment: Instead of saving two copies of data isn't it a lot easier to just un-escape data send it to user to edit it and then when user sends it back just escape it again. If we assume that we escape data and then store it to database how to we handle situation when un-escaped data ends up in database, also in option 2) we dont need to escape it all the time we can always save escaped version in cache and in case of any problem just invalidate cache, however i still wonder how to handle un-escaped data in situation 1

Comment: _sigh_ guys escaping is not as hard as it seems. You encode data depending on where you're sending it, end of story. Never store it twice unless you want your dbadmin hunting you down in the middle of the night.

Comment: @D.L In many cases that isn't possible because formatting tends to be lossy.  You can necessarily know what the original format was.

Comment: @Luc -  That's a nice theory, but it really doesn't work for systems that are designed for very high traffic.

Comment: @Xander I've never come across a system that needs that kind of performance. Google perhaps, or 4chan, but not any common website most of us will work on. It's not common to store things double.

Comment: @Luc  I do work on systems that serve large, high traffic web site, so I'll grant you that's where my bias (and my initial consideration) lies.   I'll agree that it isn't a technically preferable option in many cases.

Comment: @Luc  - I missed your comment about dbamins earlier, but that is also factually incorrect.  Production DBSa don't tend to care what your data you store or how you store it.  They only care that the database grows and performs predictably.

Comment: @Xander Actually the DBAs here do care, but I removed my downvote in response to your previous comment and edit. Though not applicable everywhere, you have a fair point.